# How can I pass an *ngIf value from one component to another?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a common component called `PreloaderComponent` and I have included it in another component. I need to know how to pass a variable from the parent component to the `PreloaderComponent` in order to work with an `*ngIf` statement in the template.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="preloader" *ngIf="loader">
    <div id="status">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
export class PreloaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  loader:any;

  ngOnInit() {}

  startLoader(){
    this.loader = true;
    //console.log("start loader="+this.loader);
  }
}

export class NativeExecutiveSummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.preloader.startLoader();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make a loader service which has loader as a subject . Then you can push the next value to it from component and subscribe it in another component which will show loader. Does it make sense?

Comment: if it's a parent-child situation use `@Input()` for Parent > Child and `@Output()` for Child > Parent. If you will use the value for more them two components, and they are not parents, use a service with a private value and getter/setter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ViewChild component method to call method from one component to another component. Write this code in your `NativeExecutiveSummaryComponent` class. See below code:

```js
// declaration
@BaseImport.ViewChild(PreloaderComponent)
private preloaderComponent: PreloaderComponent;

// use
this.preloaderComponent.startLoader();
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a common service which has `loaderSource` as a `BehaviourSubject` and inject the service into the constructor of your component and subscribe to the `loader` Observable.

**loader.service.ts**

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {

  private _loaderSource:any = new BehaviourSubject<any>({});
  public loader = this._loaderSource.asObservable();

  //set the loader value
  setLoader(loader){
    this._loaderSource.next(loader);
  }
}
```

**preloader.component.ts**

```js
import { LoaderService } from '../services/loader.service.ts'

export class PreloaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _loaderService: LoaderService) {}

  public loader:any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this._loaderService.loader.subscribe(load => { this.loader = load });
  }
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```js
import { LoaderService } from '../services/loader.service.ts'

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _loaderService: LoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._loaderService.setLoader(true); // this will set the loader value
  }
}
```

Your `loader` var will now contain the value `true` and will work with your `*ngIf`

Comment: I added code to show how you can set the loader from the parent component of your `PreloaderComponent`

Comment: this._loaderService.loader.subscribe(load => { this.loader = load }); here .loader showing error

Comment: Property 'loader' does not exist on type 'LoaderService'.

Comment: That means it can't find the loader variable. You need to add `public loader = this._loaderSource.asObservable();` into your `LoaderService`.

Comment: that issue solve...now i am getting ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PreloaderComponent -> LoaderService]:  error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180510/discussion-between-sandeep-nambiar-and-blueprintchris).

Answer (score 0):

In your NativeExecutiveSummaryComponent's HTML file, you might be having code something like this:

```html
<app-preloader></app-preloader>
```

Give this tag an Id like this:

```html
<app-preloader #preloaderId></app-preloader>
```

Then inside your NativeExecutiveSummaryComponent, You can access this element using `Viewchild` like this:

```js
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
.
.
export class NativeExecutiveSummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('preloaderId') preloaderElement: PreloaderComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.preloader.startLoader();
  }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: not working....it is calling this.preloader.startLoader() method...but this.loader = true; not working

Comment: this.preloaderElement.startLoader(); works for me...but i have another function to make this.loader = false; but it is not working

Comment: @SandeepNambiar Please see my answer. Using a common service is the correct way to do it.